# Extract a fixed-length character in R

Tags: r, split

I have an attribute consisting DNA sequences and would like to translate it to its amino name. 
So I need to split the sequence in a fixed-length character that is 3.
Here is the sample of the data

```
data=c("AATAGACGT","TGACCC","AAATCACTCTTT")
```

How can I extract it into:

```
[1] "AAT" "AGA" "CGT"
[2] "TGA" "CCC" 
[3] "AAA" "TCA" "CTC" "TTT"
```

So far I can only find how to split a string given a certain regex as the separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
strsplit(data, '(?<=.{3})', perl=TRUE)
```

Or

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(data, '.{1,3}')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
as.list(gsub("(.{3})", "\\1 ", data))
[[1]]
[1] "AAT AGA CGT "

[[2]]
[1] "TGA CCC "

[[3]]
[1] "AAA TCA CTC TTT "
```

or

```
 regmatches(data, gregexpr(".{3}", data))
[[1]]
[1] "AAT" "AGA" "CGT"

[[2]]
[1] "TGA" "CCC"

[[3]]
[1] "AAA" "TCA" "CTC" "TTT"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, still one liner, but less elegant than the other ones (using `lapply`):

```
lapply(data, function(u) substring(u, seq(1, nchar(u), 3), seq(3, nchar(u),3)))
#[[1]]
#[1] "AAT" "AGA" "CGT"

#[[2]]
#[1] "TGA" "CCC"

#[[3]]
#[1] "AAA" "TCA" "CTC" "TTT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(data, "...")
```